Ghost/horror film from 80's or 90's on BBC or ITV
I remember watching part of a film (in English) when I was a child about a town plagued by invisible spirits after dark.
I seem to think it was set in a town by the sea, and after dark, everyone had to stay inside as spirits would roam the town and kill people staying outside.
I think someone was killed when they were trying to get their washing in (?), and didn't make it back inside, or get locked out? 
I also seem to remember someone going down to the beach at night, and then ending up in a hole shaped like a bath in the sand, and being pulled back and forth by the spirits. There may have been acid or something in the hole.
I didn't finish watching it as it scared me, but I'd like to revisit it now. 

Do you remember the language/country? How old was the film? And were the spirits invisible?

I believe it was Engliah, as it was advertised on BBC or ITV.

And yes, they were invisible.

I believe the film you want is Cry For the Strangers from 1982.
It's about a couple moving to a house on the edge of a cliff in a coastal town. The residents aren't particularly welcoming. Every time there's a thunder/lightning storm someone dies in a mysterious way. Not seen it myself for some time, but it's all to do with ghostly American Indians performing rituals, and people killed and buried up to their necks in sand on the beach.
As a child, I too watched it late one night on either BBC or ITV when I probably should have been in bed. It was the washing line scene that stuck in my mind.
Hope this is what you are looking for.
All the Best.

Plot points, a couple move to a house on the edge of a cliff in a coastal town. The residents aren't particularly welcoming. Every time there's a thunder/lightning storm someone dies in a mysterious way. Not seen it myself for some time, but it's all to do with ghostly American Indians performing rituals, and people killed and buried up to their necks in sand on the beach.

Added to the answer. Looks like a good match.

Could it be The Fog? With Jamie Lee?
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080749/?ref_=nv_sr_2

Could you add some information about how this film matches the given description?

No, I've seen the Fog, and it's not that.
